# On click even for divs of a specific class Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have been following:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Introduction_to_Ext_2.0

And using the following example:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var paragraphClicked = function(e) {
        Ext.get(e.target).highlight();
    }
    Ext.select('p').on('click', paragraphClicked);
});
```

I am using something very similar:

```
   Ext.onReady(function() {
        var paragraphClicked = function(e) {
            Ext.get(e.target).addClass('product-selected');
        }
        Ext.select('.product').on('click', paragraphClicked);
    });
```

However it does not appear to work correctly. e.target appears to return the ext viewport object.

I am actually using Ext 3 not 2 so I guess there must be differences.

Comment: Without seeing your page markup or Ext component setup it's pretty difficult to provide any advice. The code that you did include looks fine syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

I never used `e.target`, always `e.getTarget()`.

Maybe you can try `e.getTarget(".product")` ?
Or maybe you can play with the `delegate` options of `addListener` in [Ext.Element](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element).